# How can I re-filter a scapy packet using BPF?

Tags: python, scapy, bpf

I'm writing a program that needs to re-filter the packets captured by sniff().I want to apply BPF filer to each packet and if it matches, return true, else return false.

Could any one give me some hints?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this is my answer on the [issue you have opened](http://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/818):

You don't need a `BytesIO` object, since the `offline` parameter of `sniff()` can accept a `PacketList` or a single `Packet`.

You can do:

```
pkts=sniff(count=10)
pkts_icmp = sniff(offline=pkts, filter='icmp')
```

The data is passed to a `tcpdump` process through its standard input, so it won't touch your hard drive, unless you're using MacOS X (but that's a tcpdump / MacOS X limitation, Scapy cannot do better here).

If you want a per packet test, you can do:

```
pkts = sniff(count=10)
for pkt in pkts:
    if sniff(offline=pkt, filter='icmp'):
        print 'match!'
```

Please not that this will fork a `tcpdump` process for each packet, which is probably not ideal.

As a side note, if your test is that simple, you can also use a Scapy test instead (it's not strictly equivalent though, but can be helpful in some situations and will not fork a process for each processed packet):

```
pkts = sniff(count=10)
for pkt in pkts:
    if ICMP in pkt:
        print 'match!'
```